# self.canDisplayBannerAds conflicting with constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

In iOS 7.1, using `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES` to display iAds seems to pushing content up when it shouldn't be.

[Here is a sample project running in the iOS 7.0.3 simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HQI9.png)

[And here is the same project running in the iOS 7.1 simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3vnu.png)

If I remove the vertical spacing constraint between the two views the bug doesn't appear.

Is this simply a bug in iOS or a problem with my

Here is the sample project if anyone wants to give it a try:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4521046/iPhoneUITest.zip

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem but in iOS 8. I had two buttons having round corners to create a circle using their width divided by 2.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.instructionsButton.layer.cornerRadius = self.instructionsButton.frame.width / 2
}
```

The buttons would not be a full circle until after the iAd showed. I added:

```
 self.originalContentView.layoutSubviews()
```

Into my viewDidLayoutSubviews:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.originalContentView.layoutSubviews()
    self.instructionsButton.layer.cornerRadius = self.instructionsButton.frame.width / 2
}
```

This fixed the buttons to have the correct constraints on load.
The documentation for canDisplayBannerAds states: "The impact is that the view controller's view property will no longer return the originally provided view, it will return the new container. To access the original view, use the originalContentView property." You have to remember to use originalContentView for self.view.